# Setting a global currency dropdown

Tags: symfony, session, routes, symfony4

I would like to setup a dropdown listing some currencies on all the pages of my website (Symfony 4.4). 
The value set in this dropdown will then be used to adjust/convert the prices to the user's favorite currency. 
I have been playing around some sessions parameters but it's not satisfactory. I feel like I need to place a hook in of the events, but I am not sure which event I should use.
I am thinking something like this

```
-- Request --
-- Event catcher --
  If (currency not set in the session) then set currency to default (e.g. USD or EUR), I will probably base this on the user's locale
-- Send reply --
```

The tricky bit is to change the currency. I guess I need to set a route to change the session parameter and redirect to the current route.

I also thought about adding the currency in the route (which would be my favorite option), but I already have a language prefix (_locale) and I am not sure how I can apply multiple prefixes...
Thank you for any help or direction

Comment: when you say "user" do you actually mean User or a session? If it's the latter, you can literally take a look at how symfony handles locales, since it's literally the same concept. Symfony uses an event listener, and you can certainly set it on the session instead of (or additionally to) the router context to make it sticky

Comment: User here is any person using the application. There is indeed a bit of dedicated documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/session/locale_sticky_session.html). It is also mentioned that we should avoid creating sessions when not necessary, so I'll explore the route option further. At the end of the day, it is about making it work with my LanguageListener and handle multiple prefixes for the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I ended up creating a Form that I called through a separate render query containing the new currency value and a redirect path to the current page.